# tabularray, math columns, empty cell error

Tags: tabularray

Why the following MWE

```
\documentclass[border=3.14159]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewColumnType{L}{>{$}l<{$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={L l},
             }
a_i &   b   \\ 
%
    & text  \\
x_i & text  \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

gives error:

```
Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
```

A rude cure can be inserting `~` or `$$` in empty cells, but this is quite annoying. I wonder, if cause of this error can be considered as bug or is my definition of math column too rude?

Comment: I have added `$` and `$$` options. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @L.J.R., thank you very much for info! I will wait on MiKTeX update with this package version.

Comment: To down voter! What is wrong with my question that you (after two years) down wote it? Is it so dummy? From answer I can't conclude this. Or you simply hate me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated on 2021-09-15:** I have added `$` and `$$` options for cells/columns/rows (see issue [#45](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/45)). You may try the latest package file https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/raw/main/tabularray.sty or wait for version 2021P scheduled on 2021-10-01.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14159]{standalone}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\NewColumnType{L}{Q[l,$]}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
  hlines, vlines,
  colspec={Ll},
}
  a_i &   b   \\
      & text  \\
  x_i & text  \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

It seems it is better to provide `$` option for `Q` column just as `tabu` package. I have create an issue here:
https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/45

At this time you could add a `\relax` as a workaround:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14159]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewColumnType{L}{>{$\relax}l<{$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={L l},
             }
a_i &   b   \\ 
%
    & text  \\
x_i & text  \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  This works fine. At preparing a `Q[$]` option I suggest that it will be able to use in configuration something like `\NewColumnType{Y}[1][]{>{$\displaystyle\relax}Q[co=1,#1]<{$}}`. I also have a (big) wish, that you will ad to package documentation description how to define mat columns.

Comment: Yes, it would be `X[$$]` just as in `tabu` package.